# How can we change the default shutdown mode of an Avalonia application

Tags: c#, .net, avalonia

Iam trying to build an cross platform desktop application using avalonia(.net 6). Actually Iam new to avalonia. I want to shutdown my application explicitly. The default shutdown mode OnLastWindowClose , I want to change it to OnExplicitShutdown. I got a hint that it want to configure  in the Application Lifetime at App axaml.cs .  But I don't know how to do it.
Anyone please help me. Please give me a detailed description about each and every step to configure it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it in Main() via [StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(T, string[], ShutdownMode)](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia/ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetimeExtensions/8D9FED7F) method.

EG: In the "Avalonia Application" project template you can set it as follows in *Program.cs*:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => BuildAvaloniaApp()
    .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args, ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown);
```

I've also seen it set in OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted() in App.axaml.cs, but I've not tested it...

```
public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
{
    if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
    {
        desktop.ShutdownMode = Avalonia.Controls.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
    }

    base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
}
```

There is some background information in the Avalonia documentation:
[Application-lifetimes](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/concepts/application-lifetimes)